# PdfBook Extension - MediaWiki - Fullurl parser function link automatically to every category page

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am able to display a download link in category to download all the pages of that category.

In the below link, it is written as

**In order to include this parser function link automatically to every category page, add it to the Mediawiki:Categoryarticlecount page.**

Rather than adding the download link manually to all categories, i tried the above. That is, added the download link in Mediawiki:Categoryarticlecount page to automatically include the fullurl parser function link to every category page. But it didnt work.

```
 Parser function link : [{{fullurl:{{FULLPAGENAME}}|action=pdfbook}} | Download]
```

How to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two typos in there:

1. The system message is at `MediaWiki:Category-article-count` (note the camel-case in `MediaWiki`)
2. The external link syntax is `[url text]`, not <s>`[url | text]`</s>, so it should be `[{{fullurl:{{FULLPAGENAME}}|action=pdfbook}} Download]`

Other than that, your code looks fine.